# Why is google streetview not displaying image for some coordinates?

Tags: google-maps, google-street-view

I am having an issue where some coordinates are providing correct streetview image while others are off by several lots.  For example, the coordinates for 42.4025192834409,-83.1636018491871 in streetview bring me to the intersection nearby. If I enter those coordinates into google maps the pin location is correct but then I can't drag the streetview icon in that section. Is there anything we can do differently with our coordinates so that they go to correct location for streetview?

Answer (score 1):

When I search for the address it works as you are seeking. I think this is the discrepancy you are experiencing:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/streetview/intro

> The Google Street View Image API will snap to the panorama photographed closest to this location. When an address text string is provided, the API may use a different camera location to better display the specified location. When a lat/lng is provided, the API searches a 50 meter radius for a photograph closest to this location.

You may want to try reverse geocoding.

Comment: Unfortunately we use coordinates because geocoding is not accurate enough. In the past these coordinates have worked well for streetview but recently it only works for some coordinates.

Comment: Is it possible for you to use the Place ID?

Comment: No but whatever was going wrong has been fixed - streetview is now bringing me to correct coordinates again.

Answer (score 1):

Try again now.

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?size=640x480&location=42.4025192834409,-83.16360184918&fov=90

When I read your question two days ago, it was actually getting the wrong panorama. I tried again today and it finally got the closest panorama to those coordinates. I guess it was an issue on Google's end.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know it is working correctly! I happened to notice today that it seemed to be working pretty well and sure enough these coordinates now work again.